# Updating Map with Default Constructable Class Value in C++17

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

Consider the following code in C++17:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    int attribute;
    MyClass(){
        this->attribute = 1;
    }

    void update(int x){
        this->attribute = x;
    }

};

void testing(){
    map<string, MyClass> mapping;
    MyClass one;
    mapping["hh"] = one;
    cout << one.attribute << endl; //1
    one.update(10);
    cout << one.attribute << endl; //10
    cout << mapping["hh"].attribute << endl; //1
}

int main(){
    testing();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose I have a map with a default constructable class as values and I want to update the map by accessing value with the key and then modifying the attributes. The class is and must be updated by a method. The key should remain unchanged.

What is the best way of doing this? `[]` operator does not seem to work in this case.

Comment: `mapping["hh"].update(10);`?

Comment: `one` is not the same object as the one inside the map.

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
MyClass one;
mapping["hh"] = one;
```

`one` is a distinct object, and `mapping["hh"]` will create its own object if it doesn't already exist in the `map`.  You are then assigning `one` to that second object, which will copy the current `attribute` value of `one` into that object.

Thus, `one` and `mapping["hh"]` are separate objects, which is why you see two different `attribute` values being printed.

To do what you want, you can change this:

```
MyClass one;
mapping["hh"] = one;
```

To this instead:

```
MyClass& one = mapping["hh"];
```

Now, there is only one object present, the one in the `map`, and `one` is just a reference to that object.  Now, you will see only one `attribute` value printed.